# Visual Basic - How can I continue the Script when an Attribute in the AD is empty

Tags: vba, ldap

I have created a Macro that will pull information from LDAP and insert it via bookmarks in a Word Document.
This works perfectly, unless an Attribute is empty. So in the Word Document the title is inserted before the users name, but when the user does not have a title the script stops and gives an error message.
How can I make the script skip the function if the attribute is empty in the AD?

Here is the part script, where it stops when the user doesn't have a title (at the end):

```
Sub AutoNew()
 With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyTitle").Range
 .InsertBefore GetTitle
 End With
 With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MygivenName").Range
 .InsertBefore GetgivenName
 End With
 With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Mysn").Range
 .InsertBefore Getsn
 End With
 With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MytelephoneNumber").Range
 .InsertBefore GettelephoneNumber
 End With
 With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Mymail").Range
 .InsertBefore Getmail
 End With

End Sub

Function GetTitle() As String
Dim objSysinfo As Object
Dim objUser As Object

Dim strUser As String 'Distinguished Name

Set objSysinfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strUser = objSysinfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)

GetTitle = objUser.get("Title")

End Function
```

Would be delighted if anyone can help me.
Cheers,
Sonja

Answer (score 1):

Check if `objUser.get("Title")` is **null** or **empty** before getting the value.

Comment: Where should I put the command, and what would the command be? (im new to this, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

If IsNothing(objUser.get("Title")) then
 GetTitle = objUser.get("Title")
Else
 GetTitle = ""
End If